# Entity framework null value in query

Tags: .net, entity-framework, null

I'm seeing a strange behavior in an EF query adn I'm wondering why it is happening.
With the following code I don't get any results:

```
if (category.Parent == null)
{
    return Db.EventCategories.Where(c => c.Parent == category.Parent);
}
```

But with this code it does return the expected results:

```
if (category.Parent == null)
{
    return Db.EventCategories.Where(c => c.Parent == null);
}
```

What is the difference? Isn't null always null? or does the EF treats them as different elements when the value is a nullable (Parent is of type int?).

Comment: Do you modify the `category` object before you actually run the query?

Comment: No, I don't. I think @a1ex01 is right, if you don't use the constant null it won't generate the IS NULL query

Comment: Have you checked the generated SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think the first statement generates something like `SELECT ... 
FROM category, eventcategories WHERE category.parent = eventcategories.parent` (which returns empty recordset if category.parent is null), whereas the second `... WHERE eventcategories.parent IS NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Please see a detailed explanation in this article: [NULL Value Handling in Entity Framework](http://henrylu.me/2014/07/05/null-value-handling-in-entity-framework/). Beware that EF 5.0, 6.0 and 6.1 handle the nullable values differently. In EF 5.0, you will need to manually test for nulls; an equation comparison between two variables does not test for nulls by default. You can also turn on the **UseCSharpNullComparisonBehavior** property manually in the **DbContext.ContextOptions** to achieve the same effect. In EF 6.0, null comparison is turned on by default, but probably over-aggressively and even on non-nullable columns, resulting in slower performance. EF 6.1 is supposed to have tweaked the algorithm to only test nulls when needed.